# Which web-based remote admin tools offer Event Viewer notifications?

Tags: windows, remote-access, logmein, teamviewer, event-viewer

What options are available for web-based remote Windows PC administration (file transfer, remote desktop, etc.) that can also offer email notifications and reporting from the Windows Event Viewer?

We're finishing up a trial with LogMeIn Central which provides this functionality, however I would like to know what other options are available to compare price and features against.

I've been looking into TeamViewer, but it looks like they don't provide event log notification, which is a critical feature for us.

Are there any other players besides LogMeIn who provide Event View error reporting?

Answer (score 1):

There was a service I nearly worked for that offered some extremely powerful web-based remote monitoring and management systems that worked using a heavily modified version of VNC. It was a hosted solution that allowed for you to login to their website and view your computers. Because the VNC agent ran on each system you managed, you had real-time access to everything going on in that computer.

The service was geared towards support of SMBs wherein they'd not have to have extensive on-site IT presence, having a 24-her 800-number helpdesk with continuous remote access and awareness of all the computers.

Unfortunately I cannot recall their name. Sorry.

I have used both TeamViewer and LogMeIn. LogMeIn has some pretty good features, and they keep aggressively developing, which is good. The TeamViewer system we used was an appliance, but it only really did remote control.

Comment: That's pretty similar to our use-case. We are installing kiosk computers at various clients (museums, visitors centers, etc.) across the world, many of whom do not have solid IT support of their own. We're finding it increasingly necessary to provide this for them. It also makes the development process easier.